# Checking if string is null when string is declared using request.getParameter in java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to check if the string i declared using request.getParameter is null or empty.

But i keep getting an error when i tried doing this code:
the error is nullexception error.

```
<%
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String acctnum = request.getParameter("acctnum");
String pin = request.getParameter("pin");
String balance = request.getParameter("balance");
out.println(name+acctnum+pin+balance);
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jsp", "root", "");

String sql = "Insert into users(name, account_numer, pin, balance) values('"+name+"',     '"+acctnum+"', '"+pin+"', '"+balance+"')";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);

conn.close();
if(name != null){
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

i also tried .equals("") but to no avail.

What i am doing wrong here, i want to check whether the string is empty or null to prevent it form redirecting to another page.

Thank you

Comment: at what line you get error? and try isEmpty() may be it's help

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak i cant tell, i was looking for a line number but all it said that a root error has been encountered and cant proceed.

Comment: Look at the log file of the server

Comment: also im throwing a null value in there to check it for null, if i remove my null checker the code runs fine

Comment: ***Sanitize your inputs!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth checking out Apache's [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class, more specifically the [`isEmpty(String str)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) method:

> public static boolean isEmpty(String str) Checks if a String is empty
> ("") or null.
>
> StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
> StringUtils.isEmpty("")    = true
> StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false
> StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false
> StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
>
> NOTE: This method changed in Lang version 2.0. It no longer trims the String. That functionality is available in isBlank().
>
> Parameters: str - the String to check, may be null
>
> Returns: true if the String is empty or null

Also, you might want to use prepared statements for your SQL queries. The one you have is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: so using string != null is a bad idea? when should i use .isempty and != null? thank you. i do plan on putting some validation after i get all the basic stuff ironed out.thank you

Comment: @magicianIam: From what I have learned, null checks can get messy regardless of what objects you are checking. I think that the `Util` classes provided by Apache can help you better deal with null checks for different types. The framework will most likely be more robust than your code.

Comment: i see, thank you, it was much simplier in php, i am quite new to java web. thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're getting the exception before you reach `if(name != null)`. You are using the parameters while initializing the `sql` variable. Are you expecting `null` strings to be present while doing that?

I think you should have a null check before doing any DB related operation:

```
if (nullChecksPassed) {
    Class.forName("");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("");
    String sql = "";
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(sql);
    conn.close();
}
if (name != null) {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
```

Comment: why? could you explain it to me more why i cant work after? thank you

Comment: yes and youre right if its null they should not be entered at the DB at all. thank you for pointing that out i missed it. though if i did the null check at .execute will it redirect if it returns true to null?

Comment: In that case you should have a null check before performing any DB related operation. Let me update my answer.